# Post method working as get in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend and I am trying to delete data from grid using post method but when I click on yes button it is working as get method. The url shows this [http://project.com/client/delete/id/10?id=10&del=Yes]. Please please please someone help me out.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function deleteAction()
{

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {

        $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');

         print_r($del);die;
        if($del=='Yes')
        {

          $id =$this->getRequest()->getPost('id');  

        $client = new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getparam('id');

        $client->deleteClient($id);


      }
```

My delete.phtml code

Are you sure that you want to delete

```
<?php foreach($this->client as $clients): ?>
'<?php echo $this->escape($clients['firstname']); ?>'
'<?php echo $this->escape($clients['lastname']); ?>'
'<?php echo $this->escape($clients['email']); ?>'
</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->url(array('action'=>'delete')); ?>" method="post">
<div> 

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $this->escape($clients["Id"]); ?>"/>

<input type="submit" name="del" value="Yes" />
<input type="submit" name="del" value="No" />

 </div>

 </form>
```

[image: Screenshot of database structure]

Table

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
["Id"]=>
string(1) "1"
["firstname"]=>
string(5) "tuhin"
["lastname"]=>
string(6) "biswas"
["email"]=>
string(15) "tuhin@gmail.com"
  }
  [1]=>
 array(4) {
["Id"]=>
string(1) "2"
["firstname"]=>
string(5) "Ankur"
["lastname"]=>
string(7) "raiyani"
["email"]=>
string(15) "Ankur@gmail.com"
  }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
["Id"]=>
string(1) "5"
["firstname"]=>
string(5) "Tejas"
["lastname"]=>
string(5) "Patel"
["email"]=>
string(15) "tejas@gmail.com"
  }
 [3]=>
 array(4) {
 ["Id"]=>
string(1) "6"
["firstname"]=>
string(6) "Ranjan"
["lastname"]=>
string(5) "sahoo"
["email"]=>
string(16) "ranjan@gmail.com"
  }
 [4]=>
 array(4) {
["Id"]=>
string(1) "7"
["firstname"]=>
string(5) "Mansi"
["lastname"]=>
string(5) "Joshi"
["email"]=>
string(15) "mansi@gmail.com"
  }
 [5]=>
array(4) {
["Id"]=>
string(1) "8"
["firstname"]=>
string(5) "tuhin"
["lastname"]=>
string(6) "biswas"
["email"]=>
string(15) "tuhin@gmail.com"
```

Comment: From the looks of just the URL `http://project.com/client/delete/id/10?id=10&del=Yes` the values `id` and `del` are being passed as `$_GET` variables (they are part of the URL), however any form data that is going along should be going as `$_POST`.  What does a var_dump of `$id` produce?  That would be where I would start troubleshooting.

Comment: In $del also no value is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is where you put  the id

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getparam('id');
$id =$this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
```

you are assigning  the variable twice in one if condition in different ways.

I have tried to  modify your code it may work for you or not, this is untested. 
Try the following:-

in Your Controller

public function deleteAction()
{

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    $del = $this->getRequest()->getPost('del');

    if($del=='Yes')
    {

        $id =$this->getRequest()->getPost('Id');

        $client = new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();

        $client->deleteClient($id);
            }
    exit();


} else {
    $id = $this->_getParam('Id', 0);
    $client = new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
            //render the id to the view         
    $this->view->clientId = $client->getClientId($id);
}
```

}

And your Model Dbtable Client Class. Add this Method.

```
            /*In your Db Client class Table*/


public function getClientId($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id; //cast to integer.
        //here the id in your client table
        //change it  to fit it your needs
        $row = $this->fetchRow('Id = ' .$id);
        if(!$row)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find this $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();

    }
```

and in your ViewHTml
Are you sure that you want to delete ?

```
<?php foreach ($this->client as $clients) {
        echo $this->escape($clients->firstname);
        echo $this->escape($clients->lastname);                     
        echo $this->escape($clients->email);

}?>

    <form action="<?php echo $this->url(array('action'=>'delete')); ?>" method="post">

       <input type="hidden" name="Id"  value="<?php echo $this->clientId['Id']; ?>" />
       <input type="submit"name="del" value="Yes" />
       <input type="submit" name="del" value="No" />

    </form>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Mubo, but $this->client['id'] is giving undefined index error in the url.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your table. how is your primary id for client table.

Comment: I've added the sreenshot of table structure please check it.

Comment: The problem is your id in your Table is [Id] not id. So you can change you database Id name to id. or just copy the code i changed it.

Comment: Actually I am using Id instead of id. . .here the main problem is in controller the value s not coming I checked the value in $del but nothing is coming into it.

Comment: Make Table dump for me i will check it out.

Comment: I've done it please check it. It's below the screenshot.

Comment: Man when you want delete a record you are clicking on a link to delete some thing. are you sending the [Id] through the url. so that your controller gets this param like this:    $id = $this->getParam('Id',0);       The link on clicking on to delete should  have <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'client',
             'action'=>'delete','id'=>$clients->id));?>">

Comment: Every thing seems al right to me except that you have that problem in the link.

Comment: Hey it's solved, actually the error was in a phtml file where I had used two form tags.Anyways thanks a lot to bear the headache given by me ;)